# How to get values from a object

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop, object

I am new at Javascript and I'm trying to get values of id key, from array that have multi objects inthere.

```
dynamicList = [
    { id: 1, gorevAdi: "Görev 1" },
    { id: 2, gorevAdi: "Görev 2" },
    { id: 3, gorevAdi: "Görev 3" },
  ];
```

Via the for..in loop, I need the id of the objects -like 1,2 or 3- to compare with different values.

I try to do that like that:

```
function deleteTask(id) {
 
        let deletedId;
        for (let index in dynamicList) {
            if (dynamicList[index].id == id) {
              deletedId = index 
            }
        }
        
        dynamicList.splice(deletedId, 1);
        displayTasks() 
            }
```

But wehen I did that like this the deleteId value returns undefined.

Icant figur it out why is return undefined and I cant solve that.

I hope I expressed myself well, sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dynamicList is an array - for in is not recommended ( you can check more here [Why is using "for...in" for array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-for-array-iteration-a-bad-idea) )

There are multiple array methods that you can use; in your case filter method is better:

```
 function deleteTask(id) {
 
        const shallowArray = dynamicList.filter( obj => obj.id !== id);

        displayTasks() 
      }
```

Also it is usually better not to mutate the data directly, but to create a copy

Comment: The codes, belongs to a to do list app that I've been working on. If I create a copy of array, instead of mutate the data directly, I have to create a copy  of the array every single, "add task" or "delete task" event. Isin't it a bad idea? Do ı think wrong?

Comment: i meant it as a general advice; depending on situations is not always applicable

Comment: Bro can u vote the question, I need 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use filter function.

```js
const dynamicList = [{
    id: 1,
    gorevAdi: "Görev 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    gorevAdi: "Görev 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    gorevAdi: "Görev 3"
  },
];


function deleteTask(id) {
  const newList = dynamicList.filter(e => e.id !== id);
  console.log(newList)
}

deleteTask(1)
```

Comment: To delete filtered object from the original array which dynamicList I wrote dynamicList = dynamicList.filter(e => e.id !== id);

Comment: Is this a correct use.  can i do this?

Comment: @YARLIG It is the correct way to do it can you accept the answer?